# My laptop display doesn't work, but does emit a "black light"

Tags: windows-7, display, dell-inspiron, laptop-display

The display of my laptop, a Dell inspiron 1545 PP41L, all of a sudden didn't show any picture anymore. But it does give of light, but everything is black.

**What I was doing:**
Trying to restore the MBR.

**What does work:**
External screens, like TV's or PC screens, even via VGA.
I would assume it's truly broken, but it does emit light. Kind of like one's phone does, just before one turns it off.

**What I tried**
Using the hotkey to switch between laptop-display mode, external monitor mode, and dual laptop+external monitor mode.
It's actually only in dual mode that I see this **"black light"**, in "external monitor"-mode the laptop display is completely off.

Now I am reading about the inverter that might be broken, but also about someone who replaced it, but that it didn't work. How can I be reasonably certain (or rather, 100%) that is IS the inverter that is the problem?
And what is the exact professional/industrial name for this `inverter`, what term do I use to order one?

Comment: Does the dell splash screen show when you cold boot?

Comment: No it doesn't show.

Comment: Sounds like the panel has failed, if you can enter the bios using an external display, load bios defaults and save changes on exit, disconnect external monitor and see if that does anything for the display.

Comment: “it does give off light, but everything is black.” “How can I be reasonably certain that it is the inverter?” - you can’t. You can be completely positive it is NOT the inverter because the backlight is working. What you can not be sure of is if it is the screen, cable, or motherboard. It is likely the cable.

Comment: @Moab the resetting of the Bios didn't work, alas.

Comment: @Appleoddity What cable, and can I order that online somewhere? Where would I get one? I'm pretty handy so I know I can put it in myself. 


Do you mean this cable? the *Dell OEM Inspiron 15 (1545) 15.6" LCD Ribbon Cable - *LED Backlight ONLY - R267J**

https://www.parts-people.com/index.php?action=item&id=6118

Comment: i apologise if links aren't allowed.

Comment: You’ll need to disassemble the laptop. I’d recommend checking all the connections first. The cable has a sticker with a dell part number. That’s what you need. Most other components also have dell part number stickers. Probably eBay will work. It’s the cheapest thing to try. Reasonably speaking this laptop is basically not worth anything, so you’ll have to decide how much time and money you’re going to put in to it.

Comment: Reasonably speaking, € 50 for a screen and 40 for a CPU, and 50-100 for an SSD is still less than a new comparable laptop, about € 550

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. A new screen, new cpu and new SSD doesn’t make it a new laptop nor will it perform anywhere close to what a new system would. You can buy this system all day long on eBay for $50. This series came out over 10 years ago with Windows Vista. You can buy a much better refurbed system for that price.